# Implement an interface method with a concrete class

Tags: c#, interface

I have the following interfaces, one for the entity and one for some logic:

```
public interface IItem 
{ 
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenerator
{
    IList<IItem> Generate();
}
```

and implementation:

```
public class ItemA : IItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemAGenerator : IGenerator
{
    public IList<ItemA> Generate()
    {
        // do stuff
        return List<ItemA>;
    }
}
```

That implementation did not work, it says that it does not have the matching return type, so I also tried:

```
public class ItemAGenerator : IGenerator
{
    public IList<IItem> Generate()
    {
        // do stuff
        return List<ItemA>;
    }
}
```

it does not work as well, it says: cannot implicitly convert type `List<IItem>` to `List<ItemA>`.

How to make it work? what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the list as a `List<IItem>` but add `ItemA`'s to it.

```
public class ItemAGenerator : IGenerator
{
    public IList<IItem> Generate()
    {
        var list = new List<IItem>();
        list.Add(new ItemA());

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make `IGenerator` generic.  Then you can specify the type that will be returned.

```
public interface IGenerator<T> where T : IItem
{
    IList<T> Generate();
}

public class ItemAGenerator : IGenerator<ItemA>
{
    public IList<ItemA> Generate()
    {
        // do stuff
        return List<ItemA>;
    }
}
```

Comment: A new problem pops up :)  I can't do something like: `private readonly IGenerator _generator;` and then inject it in the constructor.. how will I do that?

Comment: If you're saying you need to inject generators that create different items then you'd need to go with pmcilreavy's answer.  But make sure that whatever uses the generator doesn't truely care about the concrete item type.